# "I will not be in these next two weeks." meaning?

Tags: meaning

My professor emailed me this morning that:

> "I will not be in these next two weeks."

What exactly he meant by this sentence?

Does he mean:

```
I will not be in this week, next week, nor the week after next week
```

(So totally 3 weeks he will be gone)

or

```
I will be in this week, but not next week, nor the week after next week
```

(So only two weeks he will be gone)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your professor seems to be talking quite loosely, especially as he does not refer to specific dates. But if he sent it today, Monday, I think I would assume he means the rest of this week and the following week. But as to the specific date of his return I wouldn't like to bet money on when that would be (from what he has said).

Comment: So at least he won't be in this week right?

Comment: @tankonetoone - one way to confirm your suspicion is to reply with a note containing more specific information. For example, you could reply, "Okay, if I'm understanding you correctly, I guess I'll see you sometime on or after January 4." If the professor means something else, he can correct you accordingly.

Comment: @J.R. That's exactly what I would do. If it happens that you need to see him urgently you could always try calling the office just to see if he has actually left yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would guess he means that he won't be in this week and next week, but if he were telling you this later in the current week, (Let's say thursday or friday (Doesn't really matter.)) Then I would Guess he is meaning he won't be in next week and the week after.

But in almost all cases he probably means this week and next week. especially early in the week like this.

*If you would like more about why this is true, or the answer doesn't make a lot of sense, comment and I'll try to help.*